# Materialize tabs in modal not showing content

Tags: css, tabs, modal-dialog, materialize

I am creating a modal using materialize and in it i am trying to place swipe-able tabs.

The strange thing that is happening is that tabs header appears but the tab content does not appear at all. How can i fix this?

Here is my fiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7rmbd6w/2/) and let me tell you that this is all code copied from the documentation

```
<div id="profession-registration-modal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Register your profession</h4>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">Test 1</div>
            <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Test 2</div>
            <div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 green">Test 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of tab content sets `height: 0px` by default. You can set it in your css :

```
div.tabs-content.carousel.carousel-slider {
  height: 200px !important;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/y7rmbd6w/11/)

Comment: thanks it worked. but now the swipe feature is not working for some reason if you might know why. But anyways the content is now visible! Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to have content only then you could have omitted `swipeable: true`.

Comment: No i init the tabs as follows `$('.tabs').tabs({
        swipeable: true
    });`

Comment: @Combinu Your welcome. About swipe feature problem; if you open your jsfiddle example and change tabs, swipe feature not works. but if you open https://materializecss.com/tabs.html and change materialize example swipeable tabs and after that change tabs in your fiddle, swipe feature works! Maybe this bug happen in jsfiddle. in my opinion test this code in your computer

Comment: I am actually using directly on my code not on jsfiddle and it is not working. I think the problem is deeper. Maybe because i am using swipe in modal?

Comment: i have created a new question because i cant fix it :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903051/materialize-swipe-tabs-not-working-in-modal

Comment: @Combinu I think the problem is not related to swipe feature

Comment: yes i think so too. i created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903051/materialize-swipe-tabs-not-working-in-modal