# Materialize swipe tabs not working in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, modal-dialog, materialize

I am encountering a strange problem.
I am using swipe on materialize tabs and when i make swipe without the modal it works fine but when i include them in the modal the swipe feature does not work anymore

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.modal').modal();
   $('.tabs').tabs({
      swipeable: true
   });
})
```

```css
div.tabs-content.carousel.carousel-slider {
  height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <li><a href='#profession-registration-modal' class='orange darken-1 modal-trigger'>Open</a></li>

<div id="profession-registration-modal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Register your profession</h4>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">Test 1</div>
            <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Test 2</div>
            <div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 green">Test 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7rmbd6w/13/)

Comment: It's yummy, after resizing browser screen, swipe feature works properly

Comment: sometime it does work actually!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the modal is hidden by default, normal initialization of tabs within modals won't work. You can use callbacks like onOpenEnd to reinitialize your tabs so that they render correctly once the modal is fully opened.

```
$('.modal').modal({
  onOpenEnd: function(el) {
    $(el).find('.tabs').tabs({ swipeable: true });
  }
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle that uses that callback: https://jsfiddle.net/y7rmbd6w/14/

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery is no longer a dependency in Materialize CSS, so in order to do it with vanillaJS, one can use this -

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const options = {
        onOpenEnd: (el) => {
        M.Tabs.init(el.querySelector('.tabs'), {
          swipeable: true
        });
      }
    }
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    let instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
});
```